# Python: Hours between two datetimes by day

Tags: python, python-datetime

I tried to develop a `Python` function that determines the difference between two `datetime` objects. I need an algorithm that calculates the number of hours per day. Is there a built-in function for this?

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date

def getHoursByDay(dateA, dateB):
    ...

dateA = datetime.strptime('2018-09-01 09:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
dateB = datetime.strptime('2018-09-03 11:30:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

hours = getHoursByDay(dateA, dateB)

print hours

# {
#   '2018-09-01': 15,
#   '2018-09-02': 24,
#   '2018-09-03': 11.5,
# }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in function, though it is very simple to build one.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time

def deltaByDay(dateA, dateB):
    dateAstart = datetime.combine(dateA, time())
    dateBstart = datetime.combine(dateB, time())
    result = {}
    oneday = timedelta(1)
    if dateAstart == dateBstart:
        result[dateA.date()] = dateB - dateA
    else:
        nextDate = dateAstart + oneday
        result[dateA.date()] = nextDate - dateA
        while nextDate < dateBstart:
            result[nextDate.date()] = oneday
            nextDate += oneday
        result[dateB.date()] = dateB - dateBstart
    return result

def deltaToHours(delta, ndigits=None):
    return delta.days * 24 + round(delta.seconds / 3600.0, ndigits)

dateA = datetime.strptime('2018-09-01 09:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
dateB = datetime.strptime('2018-09-03 11:30:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
deltas = deltaByDay(dateA, dateB);
output = {k.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'): deltaToHours(v, 1) for k, v in deltas.items()}
print(output)
# => {'2018-09-01': 15.0, '2018-09-02': 24.0, '2018-09-03': 11.5}
```

Answer (score 0):

The built in timedelta functions would be able to get you the total days, and the remaining hours difference. If you want the output specifically in that dictionary format posted you would have to create it manually like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta

def getHoursByDay(dateA, dateB):
    if dateA.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") == dateB.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"):
        return {dateA.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"): abs(b-a).seconds / 3600} 
    result = {}
    delta = dateB - dateA
    tomorrow = dateA + timedelta(days=1)
    day1 = datetime.combine(tomorrow, time.min) - dateA
    result[dateA.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")] = day1.seconds / 3600
    for day in range(1, delta.days):
        result[(dateA + timedelta(days=day)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")] = 24
    priorday = dateB - timedelta(days1)
    lastday = dateB - datetime.combine(priorday, time.min)
    result[dateB.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")] = lastday.seconds / 3600
    return result
```

Essentially this function calculates the first day and the last day values, then populates all the days in between with 24.

Comment: This will lie if botg datetimes occur on the same date.

Answer (score -1):

There is a kind of simple way to do this.

```
hours = (dateA - dateB).hours
```

I've used this to caclulate a difference in days.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta

Comment: I'm unsure if timedelta has .hours

Comment: Sorry, but I do not need the full difference between the two datetime objects, but the number of hours between the two objects per day.